# Limit join to one row using knex

Tags: greatest-n-per-group, knex.js

I am trying to fetch data from two tables using a join. The problem is forum_posts will contain several items with the same thread_id. I would only like to get the first one, either by id or by creating date.

```
function getByGroup(groupId) {
    return knex('forum_threads')
        .select('forum_threads.id', 'forum_threads.updated_at', 'forum_posts.content')
        .where('forum_threads.group_id', '=', groupId)
        .leftJoin('forum_posts', function() {
            this.on('forum_posts.thread_id', '=', 'forum_threads.id');
        })
        .orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
        .then(function(threads) {
            return threads;
        });
}
```

I would like to add a limit(1) or a min to the join but not entirely sure how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a filter like the following to your left join criteria:

```
.andOn('forum_posts.created_at', '=', knex.raw("(select min(created_at) from forum_posts where forum_posts.thread_id = forum_threads.id)"))
```

This says to include the forum post record (as a left join match) if it has the minimum `updated_at` value for that `id`.

The full code. The below code isn't tested, although I did test the above snippet in a piece of my code.

```
function getByGroup(groupId) {
  return knex('forum_threads')
    .select('forum_threads.id', 'forum_threads.updated_at', 'forum_posts.content')
    .where('forum_threads.group_id', '=', groupId)
    .leftJoin('forum_posts', function() {
        this.on('forum_posts.thread_id', '=', 'forum_threads.id')
            /* The new line here */
            .andOn('forum_posts.created_at', '=', knex.raw("(select min(created_at) from forum_posts where forum_posts.thread_id = forum_threads.id)"))
    })
    .orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
    .then(function(threads) {
        return threads;
    });
}
```

Cheers!

PS: You didn't ask, but something I find very helpful when debugging Knex is the `.on()` query reporting clauses:

```
    // ...
    .orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
    /* your code above */
    .on('query', function(data) {
        // outputs the SQL query you generated & runtime data bindings.
        console.log(data);
    })
    .on('query-error', function(error, obj) {
        // outputs the Knex failed query, data, etc.
        console.log("Error:", error);
        console.log("Object: ", obj);
    })
    /* your code below */
    .then(function(threads) {
        return threads;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! I am getting an error though;  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type timestamp with time zone. The error makes sense but I haven't found a good solution for it...

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your issue, but I did just notice an extra space character in the RAW code `forum_posts .id` between forum_posts and .id ? (Now fixed in my answer.)

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too, no that is not the issue. Every variant I try asks for a boolean so I am guessing instead of returning a row on the .andOn it should return a boolean instead?

Comment: Solved it;                     .andOn('forum_posts.created_at', '=', knex.raw("(select min(created_at) from forum_posts where forum_posts.thread_id = forum_threads.id)"));

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I've added your fix to my answer.